Exercise Solution book Schmüdgen
I would like to ask for a clarification about the exercise 4 pag.22 of the book "" Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert space" by Schmüdgen. The exercise is as follows "Let $T$ and $S$ be linear operators on H. Suppose that $D$ is a dense linear subspace of $\mathcal H$ such that $\mathcal D ⊆ \mathcal D(T ) ∩ \mathcal D(S)$ and $⟨T x, x⟩ = ⟨S x, x⟩$ for all $x \in D$. Prove
that $Tx =Sx$ for all $x \in \mathcal D$."
I have two counterexamples for the statement of this exercise and I would like to know if I'm missing something.
Example 1) Let us consider a non-symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then
$$
    ⟨\textrm{Sym} A.x, x⟩ = ⟨A.x, x⟩ 
    \qquad
    \forall
    x\in\mathbb R^d
$$
and $\textrm{Sym} A.(1,1)\neq A.(1,1)$ where $\textrm{Sym} A$ is the symmetric part of $A$ and the dot "." means the matrix-vector product.
Example 2) In $\mathbb R^2$, let us consider the $0-$operator and the $\pi/2-$rotation operator, denoted by $R(\pi/2)$. Then,
$$
    ⟨0.x, x⟩ = ⟨R(\pi/2).x, x⟩ =0
    \qquad
    \forall x\in\mathbb R^2
$$
and $0.x\neq R(\pi/2).x$ for $x\neq0$.

$H$ is supposed to be a complex Hilbert space.

Yes @AnneBauval, thank you. This exactly solves my problem.
